# Accessing custom properties in SASS modules

Tags: css, sass, css-variables

So, let's say I have a SASS module `_module.scss` that declares some css variables aka custom properties. When I now load this module in another SASS styleshee, let's call it `main.scss`, I have access to all SASS-variables, mixins and also rules, but not the custom properties inside of it? Am I missing something?

Example files:

```
//_module.scss
:root {
   --some-variable: red;
}
```

```
// main.scss
@use 'module';

div {
   background-color: var(module.--some-variable); // won't work, private property because of leading '-'
   background-color: module.var(--some-variable); // won't work, would have been horrible syntax as well
}
```

I could use `@import` but that is discouraged and deprecated (see [SASS Documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import)). I've tried including the variables in a pure css file `module.css`, which compiled but didn't declare any custom properties at runtime as it directly translates the `@use 'module'` from my SASS file to the exact same in CSS - which browsers don't understand obviously. It should just more or less copy the content of a pure css file but it doesn't. Sure, I could try writing mixins in my modules that set the variables but that's just a workaround.

Am I missing something? Do I really need to write a mixin, that sets the variables and needs to be loaded? This makes the use of custom properties within modules pretty cumbersome.

**EDIT**

Forgot to mention, that `background-color: var(--some-variable)` doesn't work either even though it should according to the [documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use), since rules should just be applied directly without scoping.

Comment: Can't you use SASS variables instead of CSS variables?

Comment: I could of course but that renders them static. The custom properties can be changed during runtime with JS code, changing grids, colors, font-sizes etc on the fly if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh. The issue is most definitely the fact that my VS Code extension uses LibSass and not Dart Sass. Therefore `@use` is not yet supported in most environments. The documentation should most definitely be more explicit about this especially when warning about the use of `@import`.

Since I know it works with `@import` the issue is resolved though I'd love to see the module system being included in LibSass as well.

**tl;dr**

Do no use `@use` if you're not absolutely certain that you use Dart Sass!